# C++ WinRT - CanvasBitmap, How to dynamically create a bitmap, draw a pixel on it then display to screen?

Tags: uwp, set, windows-runtime, pixel, c++-winrt

How to:

1. Dynamically create a bitmap at size 512x512.
2. Draw a pixel with color such as SetPixel( x, y, color ) on the bitmap;
3. Display this bitmap created to Panel screen ?

From Win2D Github, the author advised to use CanvasBitmap.SetPixelBytes, obviously is very hard to find a working sample in C++ WinRT, the Win2D Gallery source downloaded and its source were merely in C# and I have to translate it into C++ and there is no single pixel writing feature.

May be I am old folk and legacy programmer, with legacy way of coding that is "Write to the screen directly" and I found many had asked such thing but cannot find a complete solution to it not to mention sample source code in C++ WinRT.

I don't want to get into Win2D, DirectX, Unity or any reason related to GPU or CPU for the moment. Moreover my COM knowledge is not there yet and looking at the  DirectX template source, already scared me away although I wrote in DirectX 2D in Win32 before.

I am new to C++ WinRT, just want a plain crystal clear sample code in C++ WinRT with XAML for UWP written based on the 3 statements above.

Once it is solved, I can port my 3D knowledge easily to WinRT UWP platform.

Any idea or reference is greatly appreciated.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, a [WriteableBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap) can be used to render into an in-memory bitmap.

For a full working example, start with a *"Blank App (C++/WinRT)"* template (call it *"WriteableBitmapSample"*). That gives you a good starting point, a complete application with a single page.

To set up the `MainPage` to make room for the bitmap, use the following code inside the generated *MainPage.xaml* file:

```xaml
<Page
    ...

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="ClickHandler" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">Generate bitmap</Button>
        <Image x:Name="myBitmap" Width="512" Height="512" />
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Remove everything that's not needed from the generated *MainPage.idl*:

```
namespace WriteableBitmapSample
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MainPage : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page
    {
        MainPage();
    }
}
```

Now moving onto the implementation (inside *MainPage.cpp*). Most of this is implemented in the `ClickHandler`, with a global `SetPixel` helper:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"

#include "MainPage.h"

#include "MainPage.g.cpp"

#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Core.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.h>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::UI;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging;

namespace
{
void SetPixel(WriteableBitmap const& bitmap, int32_t const x, int32_t const y, Color const col)
{
    auto w { bitmap.PixelWidth() };
    // Get pointer to in-memory buffer
    auto p { bitmap.PixelBuffer().data() };
    // Calculate memory offset (4 bytes per pixel)
    auto offset { w * y * 4 + x * 4 };
    // Write pixel
    auto pixel_address { p + offset };
    *(pixel_address + 0) = col.B;
    *(pixel_address + 1) = col.G;
    *(pixel_address + 2) = col.R;
    *(pixel_address + 3) = col.A;
}
} // namespace

namespace winrt::WriteableBitmapSample::implementation
{
MainPage::MainPage() { InitializeComponent(); }

void MainPage::ClickHandler(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
{
    // Create bitmap
    auto const width { 512 };
    auto const height { 512 };
    auto bitmap { WriteableBitmap(width, height) };

    // Construct gradient bitmap
    for (int32_t x = 0; x < width; ++x)
    {
        for (int32_t y = 0; y < height; ++y)
        {
            SetPixel(bitmap, x, y, ColorHelper::FromArgb(255, 255, x / 2, y / 2));
        }
    }

    // Set image source for the XAML interface
    myBitmap().Source(bitmap);
}
} // namespace winrt::WriteableBitmapSample::implementation
```

Take special note, that the `SetPixel` implementation is a lot slower than it appears. Calling the `data()` member on the `PixelBuffer` invokes a `QueryInterface`, `AddRef`, and `Release` call. For every single pixel.

Ideally, this should be called from an asynchronous handler, but I was unable to manipulate a `WriteableBitmap` from a thread other than the UI thread. That seems to be a restriction of `DependencyObject`'s (see [DependencyObject.Dispatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.dispatcher)), from which `WriteableBitmap` derives.

Comment: I noticed the SetPixel() cannot be held under timer routine, such as:

MainPage::OnInit()
{
    m_wb = WriteableBitmap( m_io.sx_max, m_io.sy_max );
    m_pb = m_page[n].wb.PixelBuffer().data();

    m_img.Source( m_wb );
.

Comment: That depends on the timer you use. If you are using a [DispatcherTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer) on the UI thread, you should be able to access a `WriteableBitmap`. If you are using a [ThreadPoolTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.threading.threadpooltimer), on the other hand, you cannot use a `WriteableBitmap`, unless you move the access onto the UI thread (e.g. by `co_await`ing a `resume_foreground` object).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `WritableBitmap` class, you can manipulate the pixels of a bitmap directly thru the [WritableBitmap.PixelBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixelbuffer#examples) property.

There is a sample on the page. at the top-right corner of the page, choose your preferred language as `C++/WinRT`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I miss out the upper C++ /WinRT option. I will try again as I also came across this page but using namespace winrt; not sure will work or not, will try.

Comment: I resolved this issues already.

For the final WriteableBitmap to be displayed under Timer routine, it had to be new bitmap object where both  auto bitmap { WriteableBitmap(width, height) } and myBitmap().Source(bitmap); must be held under Timer routine, it cannot be myBitmap().Source(bitmap) alone.

I have checked, there is no memory leaks doing this way. 

Thanks gain.